# Как запустить WAMP сервер с другой папки?

Tags: php, wamp, wamp-server

Мне нужно, чтобы сервер запускался с папки внутри моего сайта, а не с папки www. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Это можно как-то реализовать при помощи виртуального сервера. Как именно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как то так

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example1"
    ServerName www.example.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example2"
    ServerName www.example.org

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

источник https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html